# Xcode font picker window unable to select font collection

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, developer-tools

Font selection window that prompt out from the built in interface builder is unable to select font collection. It is stuck at a particular collection. When resizing the Font selection window, the collection column will show and immediately disappear once release the resizing.

I do not have an extra Mac, so I wish someone could help me verify this bug using latest release OS X and Xcode from App Store.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Create a new SpriteKit game from the built-in template.
2. Open the GameScene.sks file.
3. Drop a SKLabelNode into the scene from the Object Library
4. Select the SKLabelNode and change its font using the Attribute Inspector by clicking the "T" icon on the Font field.
5. The Font selection window should prompt and resizing this window will make the column appear.

**Expected Results:**

The "Font Collection" window should always appear, and able to select any font from any collection.

[image: expected result]

**Actual Results:**

The "Font Collection" window always disappear.

[image: actual result]

**Version:**

Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002) & OS X 10.11.3 (15D21)

**Notes:**

http://www.openradar.me/23181461

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/30366

---

**Update 1**

I try to install a fresh copy of Xcode (7.2.1) with another fresh OS X Yosemite 10.10.5/14F27 (with no xcode installed previously), the font collection column is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This affects all NSFontPanel instances across Xcode. (For example, it can also happen when selecting source editor fonts in Preferences, in Interface Builder inspectors, etc.) The master bug is radar://22656458.

Note that someone on the forum suggests a possible workaround:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/30366#121058

I haven't tried this, and can't say whether it's a good idea, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

defaults write -app Xcode NSFontPanelAttributes -string "1,0"

try this command in terminal, then restart Xcode